# How can I add a nested WPF window with a class reference within a root window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window, nested

I would like to do something such as the following, but I am getting an error that, "The attribute 'Class' from the XAML namespace is only accepted on the root element." Well, I guess my question is how can I abstract a Window class (in this case, the issue is with SomeOtherWindowClass below) out (since I have this class added to my project as a WPF window), and include it as a sub-window in my project?

```
<Window x:Class="myLogViewer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="myLogViewer" 
        Height="600" 
        Width="800" 
        Background="Black" 
        BorderBrush="Black" 
        Style="{DynamicResource MainWindow}" 
        WindowStyle="None">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Window x:Name="myOtherLogViewerWindow"
                x:Class="myLogViewer.SomeOtherWindowClass"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                Background="Black" 
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Style="{DynamicResource myOtherLogViewerWindow}"
                WindowStyle="None"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: You can't have a `Window` inside a `Window`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JeffRSon 3 - I want to create a docking environment where a window can have multiple tab controls on it and I can snap and unsnap a window to another window. I was trying to achieve this type of relationship by abstracting out a window class that could handle all of this for me, so that I could keep creating and snapping windows to other windows and keep all the logic in the main window class (in this case, SomeOtherWindowClass would have contained the logic)...making it much simpler to unsnap a window and snap a window back of this type. Now how could I achieve this?

Comment: My first thought is: Use usercontrols so you can visualize them into windows or others control like tabs, as you want.

Comment: @michele - Do you know of any good examples I can look at?

Comment: @Alexandru no, actually I never had the need to build up a solution like the one you need. But, just a quick google research bring me to this http://avalondock.codeplex.com/ for example: can it help?

Comment: @michele - These projects are honestly too complicated and too much to look into just to try and find that needle in the haystack that resembles the one little "trick" I need to get something like this up and running :P ...but I will look into using a TabControl with UserControls inside.

Comment: I went with Telerik's RadDocking, which I've found to contain absolutely everything I need!